# Custom timestamp in emacs orgmode

Tags: emacs, timestamp, elisp, org-mode

I'd like to insert a **timestamp** in a custom format in **emacs orgmode**. I want to insert just the current time (without date!) in this form: [HH:MM], by pressing `C-c -`. I am completely new to lisp and couldn't figure out how to do this.
My starting point for my `~/.emacs`-file is like this:

```
(defun org-my-custom-timestamp ()
  (interactive)
  ( :SOME_CODE: )
)


(define-key global-map "\C-c-" 'org-my-custom-timestamp)
```

Now this is just the definition of my custom function called `org-my-custom-timestamp`, the "interactivation" and a Shortcut-assignment.
However i have tried various things for `:SOME_CODE:` without any success.

What can be fitted in the function to make it work in the described way?

Does any experienced emacs-user even consider this way to tackle it practical or is there a smarter way to do it? Perhaps org-mode-internally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Org mode's local keymap has an entry that binds `C-c -`, so we have to change it instead of a global one:

```lisp
(defun org-my-custom-timestamp ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (format-time-string "[%H:%M]")))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key "\C-c-" 'org-my-custom-timestamp)))
```

Note again that it replaces the `org-ctrl-c-minus` command, which is bound to `C-c -` by default in Org mode, with your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The Code-Snippet above works just fine and does exactly what i was looking for!Since this binding would overwrite an org-mode feature I decided to find another shortcut for this command.